# remove disjoint open balls from $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ is infinite set?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $$A=[0,1] \times [0,1]$$
$$B_i = B_{r_i} (x_i), B_i \cap B_j = \emptyset \,\,\, \forall i \neq j$$
$$B= \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty B_i$$
$E=A-B,$
At one point the proof uses the fact that $E$ contains infinitely many points and I'm not sure why?

I am reading an example about perfect set,
At one point the proof uses the fact that $E$ contains infinitely many points and I'm not sure why?
I tried proof by contradiction but I couldn't find any just by properties of open and closed sets

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is $x_i,r_i$?

Comment: I edited your post because the escape character for formatting is \, not /.

Comment: Oops thank you!

Comment: xi s are elements in A, ri are arbitrary radius that allows the open balls to be disjont

Comment: Are $B_i$ subsets of $A$ or not necesarily?

Comment: yes, Bi's are subsests of A

Comment: I am not completely sure how you are defining $B_{r_i}(x_i)$. Assuming that it it is Euclidean balls with $x_i\in[0,1]^2$ and $r_i$ less than or equal to the distance from $x_i$ to the square, then the corners of the square are in $E$. Now, you can prove that you can connect the corners with a path inside $E$ by approximating the path. With zero balls removed just move straight to the other corner. When you remove a ball, if this intersects the current path, move along the path until you meet the new ball, then move along the boundary of the ball until the last point ...

Comment: ... where the path leaves the ball. The radii of the balls will tend to zero. That allows you to prove that the sequence of paths converges. I cannot find a link that I used a few weeks ago, so maybe [this one](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.03785.pdf#page=2) will do. See the paragraph on page 2, where they refer to reference [3].

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer:
the boundary of any $B_i$ would not be in any other $B_j$, and there are infinitely many elements on the boundary of any openball

(otherwise, $ \exists x \in (\partial B_i) \cap B_j$, and since $B_j$ is open there exists r>0 s.t. $B_r(x)\subset B_j$.

And since x is a limit point of B_i(boundary of open ball), $\exists y \in B_i$ s.t. |x,y|<r, and therefore $y \in B_i \cap B_j$, contradicting the disjoint assumption)

thank you all anyway